# Change a page without refreshing - Laravel / Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I've been searching around for a while not to get the answer to my question but without any luck.

I'm effectively trying to replicate the navigation structure of Soundcloud the way you can click on a link and it'll redirect the page without refreshing using Ajax/jQuery but won't duplicate content and if the user refreshes, the page is still there looking normal.

The issue I have is, I have a master template which is extended on all the views so when I make a call to pull through the page, it'll replicate the page within the div I'm pushing it too. This is resulting in two headers/sidebars etc pulling from the master template.

Another thing which I'm also trying to get this to work for is that, if I remove the master template from the view, it won't show content - but say it did, it wouldn't have styling so if I was to go to directly to that page, it'll load up without styling etc.

This is the working jQuery that pulls through the page properly:

**jQ**

```
$(".main-nav li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".content-container").load(href);
});
```

I hope this makes sense, if any more information is needed I'll try my best to provide it!

Thanks a million!

Matt

**EDIT--**

This is still active. I've done a little more digging around and thought of a another way people may be able to shed some more light to. If I wrap the extended master template on views with something like:

```
if(!$request->ajax())
@extends('master')
@endif
```

That would then only show the master template on that view if the page is being requested via ajax, right? I'm not sure if that's the correct way to go about it but it's worth a try.

As usual, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `@if(!Request::ajax())` on section that didn't need to be shown when the page was loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 2):

For what you're trying to achieve, you need a little more than just jQuery and Ajax. You need a proper JavaScript Framework in combination with some templating.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use jQuery plugin [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). With this plugin you can create any site with ajax navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some ideas.

Assume that your master layout is looking like that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            header
        </header>

        <main id="page-main">
            @yield('content')
        </main> 

        <footer>
            footer
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

For each page you have to build two views, one that contains the things that should go in the "content" section, and the other that includes the previous one extending the master layout, like that:

```
@extends(layouts.master)

@section('content')
    include partial here
@endsection
```

Then in the Controller return only the partial when the request comes from Ajax while send the full page when the request is normal.

```
Class MyController extends Controller{
    public function action1(Request $request){
        // code here

        return ($request->ajax() ? view('partial') : view('fullpage'));

    }

}
```

Assuming that only links with class ".ajax" should not refresh the page, you can use the jquery function "$.get" to return the new html.

```
$("body").on('click','.ajax',function(){
    var url = this.href;
    $.get(url, function(data){
        $("#page-main").html(data);

        //history manipulation here
    });
    return false;
});
```

Of course you need to use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to update the url.

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying and sorry for the late reply. Isn't it inefficient to have two views for every one page though? Considering my web app will be relatively big. Would it be easier to specify if the page is requested via ajax/jq via Laravel and then display the appropriate content? Not sure how this would work but it seems logical in my head haha. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, or you can create only partials and a "general" view where you include dynamically every partial.