# Check to see if a page is called via Ajax in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

This is an extension from a post I made a few days ago: [Change a page without refreshing - Laravel / Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100867/change-a-page-without-refreshing-laravel-ajax)

Basically, I'm trying to replicate the URL Structure of Soundcloud where you can click on a link, it'll load the content without refreshing the page however if you land directly on that page, it won't replicate design and effecitvely break.

I've been thinking of ways on how I can check in Laravel if the page is requested via Ajax or has been landed on without an Ajax call.

What's happening at the moment is that when I call the page, the view has a master template that's extended thus creating duplicate master templates on the one view.

I was thinking if I done something like

```
@if(!Request::ajax())
@extends('masterlayout')
@endif
```

It would work but tried and no luck.

Any help as always is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: can you show the full view code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `@extends` directive is always executed even in falsy `if`

You can add an empty layout and perform check like this:

```
@extends(Request::ajax()? 'layouts.empty' : 'layouts.master')
```

and you need add only this in layout `empty.blade.php`:

```
@yield('content')
```

---

or you can add ajax check in the master layout

```
@if(!Request::ajax())
 // all layout code
@else
   @yield('content')
@endif
```

Comment: Hi Grin this is brilliant thank you! Works a treat and exactly how I need it too! Much love!

Answer (score 1):

You can check that in your controller action.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        return "This is an AJAX call!";
    }
    return "Not an AJAX call...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, I eventually got this fixed by using `@if(!Request::ajax())` on section that didn't need to be shown when the page was loaded via ajax.

Thank you again! :D